# Handle local links to local files in emacs

Tags: emacs, macro

I have a `LaTeX` document where I often have to insert pathnames of files on my machine of other `LaTeX` files. Is there a way in `emacs` do get the following:

1. A command which opens a file selection dialogue such that the choosen filename + path will be inserted at point.
2. A macro which opens the file under point. For example when the point is on `~/mytex.tex` and I press a certain key sequence it should open `~/mytex.tex` in a new buffer.
3. A macro which opens the corresponding `pdf` file of `tex` filename under point in `evince`, for example `~/mytex.pdf`.
4. A command which opens a file selection dialogue to change the filename under point.

It is important to have the file-path names in a plain style because they should be proceed by latex as well.